# Check if object is null after each method call

Tags: java, java-8

I have this simple fragment that I would like to reengineer in a more elegant way maybe with the latest JDK 8 features:

```
String x = methodCall();
if(x==null) {x=method2();}
if(x==null) {x=method3();}
if(x==null) {x=method4();}

// doing calculation with X
```

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh The methods may possibly modify `x` and OP possibly wants to apply additional methods only if its still `null`.

Comment: You may consider Java8 Optionals a more elegant approach here (though you may also consider them overly verbose!).  FWIW in Kotlin this would be `val x = methodCall() ?: method2() ?: method3() ?: method4()`.

Comment: Please stop calling Java 8 features "latest". Java 8 is several years old. The "latest" features are in Java 9.

Comment: Java 9 has been released 5 or 6 week ago. JRE updates in production takes time. We will switch from 7 to 8 in January 2018.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Streams:

```
    Optional<String> result= Stream.<Supplier<String>>of(this::method1, this::method2, this::method3)
            .map(Supplier::get)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .findFirst();
    System.out.println(result.isPresent());
```

The above code is equal to this (generated with Intellij Idea)

```
    Optional<String> result = Optional.empty();
    for (Supplier<String> stringSupplier : Arrays.<Supplier<String>>asList(this::method1, this::method2, this::method3)) {
        String s = stringSupplier.get();
        if (s != null) {
            result = Optional.of(s);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This tells me I don't know `Stream` enough ! You want a `Supplier<String>`. BUT, **there is a small difference**, every `Supplier` will be executed here, the original code only execute the method if necessary (if there are an update in the methods, this is a problem).

Comment: @AxelH - the `findFirst` will deal with that.

Comment: @AxelH no... `findFirst` is used

Comment: Thanks for that, I thought this would still be executed ... Stream have its logic ... need to get back on it !

Comment: I must admit that this answers the question, however I can hardly find this better than the original OP's approach. This is unnecessarily complex, it's less readable, needs hints for the generic types and is longer! +1 anyway, because it answers the question, but...

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `Stream.of<Supplier<String>>` or `Stream<Supplier<String>>.of`? (The generic before the method name looks like an error to me, though I haven't used Java in a long while so I'm not sure)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: the type parameter(s) for a method invocation has/have to be right before the method name, as written in the answer. Don’t confuse with type parameters for classes applied to a constructor.

Comment: @Holger Huh, alright. I haven't done Java in a while; coming from C++ it looks odd.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner no buts... I'd use it, just to pis u off probably :)

Comment: @Eugene go ahead and pis me off :)

Answer (score 4):

The question explicitly mentions Java 8, but also mentions the "latest features". As it isn't clear which the OP wants, this answer is with the latest features.

With Java 9 you can use the new `Optional.or` method to concisely implement this logic:

```
import static java.util.Optional.ofNullable;
...
String x = ofNullable(methodCall())
    .or(() -> ofNullable(method2()))
    .or(() -> ofNullable(method3()))
    .or(() -> ofNullable(method4()))
    .orElse(null);
```

Depending on what you are doing, you might want to omit the `.orElse(null)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the `if`-block by using a designated method but besides that you won't get it more compact. Especially you will still need to check for `null` after each method.

Here is a method which uses `Optional#ifPresent` to apply a method if its not present:

```
public <V> void runIfNotPresent(V value, Runnable method) {
    if (value == null) {
        method.run();
    }
}
```

Here's your code with using that method:

```
x = methodCall();
runIfNotPresent(x, this::method2);
runIfNotPresent(x, this::method3);
runIfNotPresent(x, this::method4);

// doing calculation with X
```

Note that you can't directly use `Optional#isPresent` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--)) as its logic would be reversed. However that is also a very useful class and if you're using **Java 9** then you might want to use `Optional#or` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#or-java.util.function.Supplier-)) as others already showed in their answers.

---

Alternatively you could write your own method to chain-apply methods

```
public <V> V applyAsLongAsNull(V value, Function<V, V>... methods) {
    // Apply methods
    for (Function<V, V> method : methods) {
        if (value == null) {
            value = method.apply(value);
        } else {
            // Stop as soon as value is not null
            break;
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

You could then transform your `methodX` to a `Function<V, V>` which accepts a `String` value and returns a possibly different `String` value:

```
public String methodX(String value) {
    // Do something with value
    ...
    // Return value
    return value;
}
```

Finally you would use it like:

```
String x = methodCall();
x = applyAsLongAsNull(x, this::method2, this::method3, this::method4);

// doing calculation with X
```

Comment: You could simply do `if(value == null) value = method.apply() else break;`, then you remove everything before the loop, if the methods is empty, the loop won't execute, so `value` can be return. Basicly, using the  `Supplier` array in my answer, but with a method to iterate the array ;)

Comment: The top code snippet doesn't really equate to the code in the question. Notice that successive methods are only called if all previous calls returned `null`. Your code seems to call methods 2 through 4 if the first call **did** return something other than null.

Comment: @Henrik Yeah, you are right. The logic is reversed, thanks. I've edited the code but I don't find a nice compact `Optional` solution which don't uses **Java 9** anymore.